# Add 1 based on value in cell and value of previosc row

Tags: excel, vba

I am faced with the table on the left, and need to obtain the table on the right. 
The C column contains a string of text. When "aaa" is found then the number in column B must become the sum of the previous number(of the row containing "aaa") and 1:  B2 = 2, because there are no other "aaa" before it; B3 =3(b2+1), because "aaa" was found in previous row and it's value was 2.

This must happen for each string in column C. The desired result is seen in the right table.

I believe this call for some programming. Thank you!
  [The image can be seen here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By_KUjaB8L6TVEtIdkZXM29reUU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Your image is behind a permission asking wall, so please put it to public so that we can see it. Also I believe this problem can be simply solved making use of an array formula with some if statements and does not need to rely on VBA.

Comment: Thank you, the image is now public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:
[image]

THE RESULT IS:[image]

Answer (score 0):

simple solution

```
=countifs($I$5:I5,I5)
```

where I5 is first row with data in the table (sorry but i cant see the image)